# Find all number $z$ such that $\cos(z) = i\sin(z)$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all number $z$ such that $\cos(z) = i\sin(z)$.

> Options : $$(a) \ in, \ n\in \mathbb{Z} \\
> (b) \ inπ +1, \ n\in \mathbb{Z} \\
> (c) \ \frac{inπ}{2}, \ n\in \mathbb{Z} \\
> (d) \ \text{no solutions exist}.$$

**My try :**
Let $z=x+iy$.

Then, $\cos(z) = \frac{\exp(iz)+exp(-iz)}{2}$ and $\sin(z) = \frac{\exp(iz)-exp(-iz)}{2}$.

$$\therefore \cos(z) = i\sin(z) \\
   \implies \frac{\exp(iz)+exp(-iz)}{2} = i \frac{\exp(iz)-exp(-iz)}{2} \\
\implies \exp(iz)\big(1-i\big) = \exp(-iz)\big(-1-i) \\
\implies \frac{\exp(iz)}{exp(-iz)} = - \frac{1+i}{1-i} = -i \\
\implies \exp(i2z) = -i
$$

Now, $$i2z = -2y + i 2x$$
$$\therefore \exp(i2z) = -i \\
\implies e^{-2y}\Big(\cos(2x) + i \sin(2x)\Big) = -i$$

Therefore, $$e^{-2y}\cos(2x) = 0, e^{-2y}\sin(2x) = -1
$$
We have, $$ e^{-2y} = 1 \\
\implies y = 0$$ and $$ \cos(2x) = 0, \sin(2x) = -1 \\
\implies 2x = \Big( 2nπ + \frac{3π}{2}\Big) \\
\implies x = \Big(4nπ +3\Big) \frac{π}{4} $$

Thus the solution are the numbers, $$z = \Big(4nπ +3\Big) \frac{π}{4} , \ \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$$.

But when I'm plugging this in the given equation,. I'm getting nonsense.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Note that $sin(z)=\frac{\exp(iz)-\exp(-iz)}{2i}$ and not $sin(z)=\frac{\exp(iz)-\exp(-iz)}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you. I totally missed it.

Comment: @YumekuiMath but doing that gives me no solution. As $\exp(-iz) \ne 0$ for any $z$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Martin I already answered the question in the comments.

Comment: @Itachi: Comments can be deleted at any time and their purpose is to clarify a problem, not to answer a question. If you don't need an answer then you can delete the question. Or we close it as a duplicate, because an almost identical question has answers.

Comment: @Martin :  I'd have deleted the question but as it's already answered so it's showing that I need to vote to delete the question. Willi you then help me get some votes?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially by definition,
$$
\cos z+i\sin z=e^{iz} \tag{1}
$$
Changing $z$ into $-z$, we get
$$
\cos z-i\sin z=e^{-iz} \tag{2}
$$
and this is nonzero for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Note that from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain
$$
\sin z=\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
that you want to compare with what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

From $\cos(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2$ and $\sin(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, your equation becomes:

$$e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=e^{iz}-e^{-iz}$$

Hence

$$e^{-iz}=0$$

Conclusion?

*(if in doubt about the conclusion, note that $e^ze^{-z}=1$ for all $z$)*